# jQuery Click() image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why isn't my click working

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slotclick').click(function(){
        $(this).append('<div id=\"alertfade\"><div class=\"alert\">Slotje<font style=\"float:right;\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.location.reload()\">X</a></font></div></div>');
    });

    $('#stickyclick').click(function(){
        $(this).append('<div id=\"alertfade\"><div class=\"alert\">Sticky<font style=\"float:right;\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.location.reload()\">X</a></font></div></div>');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<img src="./../../assets/images/icons/slot.png" id="slotclick">
<img src="./../../assets/images/icons/sticky.png" id="stickyclick">
```

When it clicks, it has to open a alert window, Already done that with css!
But if i click on a image Slot or sticky it wont open

Comment: How exactly would you append a DIV to an image, an element that has no children and is self-closing ?

Comment: IF you press at the X (float: right)

Comment: Perhaps you should try [.insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) or append to a parent element.

Comment: You keep using `append()`. I do not think it does what you think it does.

Comment: But how would you insert the `X` in the image. Think about it, how would you write that HTML with elements inside an `<img>` tag, it just makes no sense.

Comment: Check out insertAfter instead of append

Answer (score 1):

Here a working demo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slotclick').click(function(){
        $(this).after('<div id=\"alertfade\"><div class=\"alert\">Slotje<font style=\"float:right;\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.location.reload()\">X</a></font></div></div>');
    });

    $('#stickyclick').click(function(){
        $(this).after('<div id=\"alertfade\"><div class=\"alert\">Sticky<font style=\"float:right;\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.location.reload()\">X</a></font></div></div>');
    });
});
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Comment: Can anybody explain, how this code is working? It's not working for me.

Comment: @Indra - It's exactly the same as the OP's code, and the fiddle doesn't work, but I guess people liked the cool button ?

Comment: Hmm, it's exactly the same code, may be he forgot to update the code after editing, but don't know how the others are accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `$(this).append`  , because the image tag can not have any childs.

So either append in body or use `.after()`  rather then append to just insert after the image

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, it was just my typing mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can't append a `<div>` to an `<img>`. If you want to add something after the image is clicked, wrap the image in a `<div>` and append onto that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

HTML:

```
<div id="slotDiv"> <img src="./../../assets/images/icons/slot.png" id="slotclick"> </div>
<div id="stickyDiv"> <img src="./../../assets/images/icons/sticky.png" id="stickyclick"> </div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#slotclick').click(function(){
    $( '#slotDiv' ).append('<div id=\"alertfade\"><div class=\"alert\">Slotje<font style=\"float:right;\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.location.reload()\">X</a></font></div></div>');
});

$('#stickyclick').click(function(){
    $( '#stickyDiv' ).append('<div id=\"alertfade\"><div class=\"alert\">Sticky<font style=\"float:right;\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.location.reload()\">X</a></font></div></div>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do i prevent line breaks?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#slotclick').click(function(){
           $(this).after('<div id=\"alertfade\"><div class=\"alert\">Slotje<font style=\"float:right;\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.location.reload()\">X</a></font></div></div>');
});

$('#stickyclick').click(function(){
           $(this).after('<div id=\"alertfade\"><div class=\"alert\">Sticky<font style=\"float:right;\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.location.reload()\">X</a></font></div></div>');
});
```

});

Because when you're writing append, the html is being like  , so you're not being able to see the dive, otherwise you're code is working.